# Disable __thread support

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm implementing a pthread replacement library which is extremely lightweight. There are several reasons why I want to disable __thread completely.

1. It's a waste of memory. If I'm creating a thousand threads which has nothing to do with the context that declares a variable with __thread  <strike>they will still allocate</strike> *the program will still have allocated* 1000*the size of that data bytes and never use it. It's simply not memory compatible with the mass-concurrency model. If we need extremely lightweight fibers with only 8K of stack, a TLS block of just 4K would be an overhead of 50% of the memory used by each thread. In some scenarios the TLS overhead would be enormous.
2. TLS is a complex standard and I simply don't have the time/resources to support it. It's to expensive. Personally I think the standard is poorly designed. It should have defined standard functions that had to be provided by the linker so thread libraries can take control over where TLS allocation takes place and insert relevant offsets and addresses it requires. Also the standard ELF implementation has been infected with pthread, expecting pthread sized structs to calculate offsets making it really hard to adapt to something else.
3. It's just a bad pattern. It encourages using globals and creating functions with static functions/side effects. This is not a territory we want to be in if we're creating correct programs that are easy to analyze.
4. If we really need "thread context" for some magic that tracks thread state behind the scenes (like for allocation or cancellation tracking) why not just expose the magic that TLS uses to understand that context in the first place? Personally I'm just going to use the `%fs` register directly. This would not be possible in libraries for obvious reasons but why should they be thread aware to begin with? Why not just design them correctly so they get the context related data they need in the first place right in the argument list?

My question is simply: What is the simplest way to disable __thread support and make clang emit errors if you accidentally used it? How can I get errors if I load a dynamic library which happens to require TLS?

Comment: What is TLA? do you mean TLS = **thread local storage**, i.E. `__thread` qualifier for GCC? And you could `#define __thread @error_thread##_LINE__`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I meant TLS. Fixed the typos. That's one solution. Something on compiler rather than preprocessor level would be better though and #define does not prevent dynamic libraries that uses __thread from accidentally being used.

Comment: Maybe you could use some linker scripts tricks to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean it will allocate 1000*the size of data?  The data isn't reserved until it's needed.  I recently fixed a linker bug, and was digging through that code.  I do agree that's slow to access though... lots of overhead.

Comment: @jszakmeister: Static TLS is actually allocated right away on the thread stack (after the pthread struct) and will take up physical process memory as long as any other address in the same page is touched by the program (which is likely). Dynamic TLS blocks are malloc'd when needed but suffer from the same problem. If a thread only use 1% of the data in that block it will still physically reserve all other data in the same page.

Comment: Also note that dynamic TLS is *dangerous* because the program will crash (it has no way to proceed and no way to detect/handle error) if allocation fails. To make it safe, one has to allocate it at thread creation and `dlopen` time, which is difficult and brings back the memory waste issue.

Comment: @HannesLandeholm Very true.  I didn't mean to make it sound like that I'm a fan of TLS.  In face, after being through the implementation of it, it's definitely frightening and much more complicated than you'd hope for.

Comment: @jszakmeister Also I see now that I worded "1000*the size of data" poorly and have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the simplest way is adding something like this unconditionally to your CFLAGS (perhaps from clang's equivalent of the gcc specfile if you want it to be system-global):

```
-D__thread='^-^'
```

where the righthand side can be anything that's syntactically invalid (a constraint violation) at any point in a C program.

As for preventing loading of libraries with TLS, you'd have to patch the linker and/or dynamic linker to reject them. If you're just talking about `dlopen`, your program could first read the file and parse the ELF headers for TLS relocations, then reject the library (without passing it to `dlopen`) if it has any. This might even be possible with an `LD_PRELOAD` wrapper.

I agree with you that, especially in its current implementation, TLS is something whose use should generally be avoided, but may I ask if you've measured the costs? I think stamping it out *completely* will be fairly difficult on a system that's designed to use it, and there's much lower-hanging fruit for cutting bloat. Which libc are you using? If it's glibc, I'm pretty sure glibc has lots of TLS it uses internally itself these days... Of course if you're writing your own threads implementation, that's going to entail a lot of interaction with the rest of the standard library, so perhaps you're already patching it out...?

---

By the way (shameless plug follows), we have [an extremely light-weight threads implementation](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread) in [musl libc](http://www.musl-libc.org) which presently does not have TLS. I don't think it would be easy to integrate with another libc (and I'm sure if you're writing your own you will find it difficult to integrate with glibc, especially glibc's dynamic linker, which expects TLS to be supported) but if you can use the whole library as-is, it may meet your needs for specific projects, or have useful code you can borrow (license is MIT).

Comment: FYI: `musl-libc` apparently cannot be built with `gcc-4.7` using `CFLAGS='-O3 -g -flto'`

Comment: @Basile: Thanks for the report. Unfortunately it seems to be an ICE (internal compiler error) linking libc.so, so it's pretty hard to know the cause without debugging the toolchain itself...

Comment: I'm not getting an ICE, but a multiple definition of `__environ`; feel free to send me an email to ask more details.

Comment: @R. I just sent you an email with the detailed output of make on my system and more details.

Comment: Yeah, the errors seemed nonsensical though; the places in the source it was citing multiple definition had nothing to do with `__environ`. I think it's a GCC bug.